# Is it safe to use LPCTSTR in a structure with the WM_COPYDATA message?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, wm-copydata

I have this structure:

```
typedef struct tagCOPY_PACKET
{
    TCHAR szFile[_MAX_PATH];
    GUID guidSignature;

} S_COPY_PACKET;
```

I prepare to send data with `WM_COPYDATA` like this:

```
CString strFile = GetFileToOpenFromFileExplorerPath();

S_COPY_PACKET sCopyDataPacket;
_tcscpy_s(sCopyDataPacket.szFile, _MAX_PATH, strFile);
sCopyDataPacket.guidSignature = CopyData_Signature;
COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
cds.dwData = COPYDATA_TYPE_MSA;
cds.cbData = sizeof(sCopyDataPacket);
cds.lpData = &sCopyDataPacket;

DWORD_PTR dwResult;
if (SendMessageTimeout(hOtherInstance, WM_COPYDATA,
                NULL, (LPARAM)(LPVOID)&cds, SMTO_BLOCK, 2000, &dwResult) != 0)
{
}
```

And at the other end:

```
BOOL CMeetingScheduleAssistantDlg::OnCopyData(CWnd* pWnd, COPYDATASTRUCT* pCopyDataStruct)
{
    if (pCopyDataStruct->dwData == COPYDATA_TYPE_MSA)
    {
        S_COPY_PACKET* pCopyPacket = (S_COPY_PACKET*)(pCopyDataStruct->lpData);
        if (pCopyPacket->guidSignature != CopyData_Signature)
        {
            // Bad GUID
            return FALSE;
        }

        if (GetLastActivePopup() != this) // Popup windows!
        {
            // TODO: Tell user?
            return FALSE;
        }

        theApp.SetFileToOpenFromFileExplorer(pCopyPacket->szFile);

        OpenFileFromFileExplorer();

        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

It works fine. I just wanted to know if it would be acceptable to change my structure like this:

```
typedef struct tagCOPY_PACKET
{
    LPCTSTR lpszFile;
    GUID guidSignature;

} S_COPY_PACKET;
```

And then use:

```
S_COPY_PACKET sCopyDataPacket;
sCopyDataPacket.lpszFile = strFile.GetBufferSetLength(_MAX_PATH);
sCopyDataPacket.guidSignature = CopyData_Signature;
COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
cds.dwData = COPYDATA_TYPE_MSA;
cds.cbData = sizeof(sCopyDataPacket);
cds.lpData = &sCopyDataPacket;
...
```

And, once the message has been posted and processed:

```
strFile.ReleaseBuffer();
```

Is it safe to use the `LPCTSTR` approach with `WM_COPYDATA` and if so, why?

Comment: From the receiving app point of view there is absolutely no difference between these two: `cds.lpData = &sCopyDataPacket;` and `cds.lpData = strFile.GetString();`.
They both point to the *local* data copy. So yes, it's absolutely acceptable, unless you're not trying to use `cds.lpData` pointer in the receiving app **after** `SendMessage` returns.

Comment: @Jovibor I get what you are saying. But I need to send this structure that contains the `GUID` and the `CString` contents.

Comment: Your `S_COPY_PACKET sCopyDataPacket;`  and `CString strFile` are both *local* data objects, right? So, what's the difference what pointer you provide in `cds.lpData = ` to? Well, here the suggestion - try both cases and see result yourself.

Comment: @Jovibor The receiving application cannot read data from the memory of the sending application. The rest does not matter.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl But it can read `S_COPY_PACKET sCopyDataPacket;` ?

Comment: @Jovibor I assume that the Windows system makes a copy of the data in the memory of the receiving application. Though it's not really relevant how it is implemented in the OS. All that matters is that only the `sCopyDataPacket` is made accessible to the receiving application. Nothing more.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl There is nothing saying about *copying* in the official `WM_COPYDATA` documentation, so i won't argue about that.

Comment: Technically you can pass a pointer via `WM_COPYDATA` if it points to memory you have allocated in the other address space (via `VirtualAllocEx`). In this case though it would be a waste of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation of `WM_COPYDATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-copydata) says:

> The data being passed must not contain pointers or other references to objects not accessible to the application receiving the data.

Therefore, when `CMeetingScheduleAssistantDlg` lives in a different executable, you cannot pass an `LPCTSTR` value. If it is in the same executable, chances are that it works.

Comment: Thanks. So the way I did it was better (with `_tcscpy_s`).

Answer (score 1):

No. `LPCTSTR` is a pointer. So the recipient application will receive a pointer to a memory location of the sender application. It would cause the recipient application to crash due to a memory violation, had it tried to access the data.

Comment: Thanks. So the way I did it was better (with `_tcscpy_s`).